# Align Text in P Tags side by side while maintaining Break-Word

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align **3** **p tags** side by side, and make them all function like a single paragraph styled with the attribute: **WordWrap:Break-Word**

So that it keeps the p tags next to each other free to move to the next line or stretch into a single line depending on the size. The end result should look soimething like this:

**This is a sample of the word streteched out:**

```
*<p>sample document<p/><p>sample document<p>sample document</p>*
```

**This is a sample of the words crunched together:**

```
*<p>sample document<p/><p>sample 
document<p>sample document</p>*
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5fdd6/75/

Here's the jfiddle with the 3 p tags.

Comment: Why can't they all be combined into one paragraph?

Comment: They all contain different links and styles so they have to be separate

Comment: They can be within a `<span>` inside a `<p>` and you could set the styling and other stuff just as easily. Perhaps your whole problem would be better addressed here. Because I believe you are going about this in a non-standard way. `<p>` tags can be made to do what you want, but you should probably using `<div>`s.

Comment: `<p>` tags are inherently `display:block` - have you tried setting yours to `display: inline-block;'

Comment: @Evan: that's what i answered.. right ??

Comment: @Sajad, Sorry didn't see your answer - although `display: inline` and `display: inline-block` are two different states. I'd assume he'd want to use just `display: inline;` ( like your answer ) to avoid inheriting margin styles.

Comment: @evan..yah..you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just try

```
p{
 display:inline;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[**DEMO here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sajadlfc/qy4qeebz/1/)

Comment: That works for the jsfiddle version, but i'm still having an issue on my site. It might just be because of an absolute positioned div. I'll post the code on my site to a jfiddle in a bit

Comment: Ok, this is the answer. I just tweaked my code a little bit by adding display:inline-block, float right and float:left to my 2 parent divs and added the display inline; word-wrap break-word; to the contianer with all the paragraphs tags. Thank you Sajad!

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fdd6/78/)

You just need to have this in css

```
p{
    float:left;
}
```

Try it..

Comment: It should look like a single paragraph. In your example the 3 p-tags are under each other not side by side like requested.

Comment: Thtas what i said in the fiddle..Change the div's width and see the changes in position of the <p> tags